# Im trying to make repeat interval

Tags: javascript

I make a switch statment in Javascript that changes every 6s .. but when it goes in case 10 it stops. I want it to start again from case 1. Any code please?

This is my interval:

```
var numri = 1;
var itr = setInterval(numrat, 6000);

function numrat() {
  switch (numri) {
    case 10:
        document.getElementById("td10").innerHTML = 'x5000';
        document.getElementById("td9").innerHTML = 'x1000';
        document.getElementById("td8").innerHTML = 'x300';
        document.getElementById("td7").innerHTML = 'x30';
        document.getElementById("td6").innerHTML = 'x10';
        document.getElementById("td5").innerHTML = 'x5';
        document.getElementById("td4").innerHTML = 'x2';
        document.getElementById("td3").innerHTML = '-';
        document.getElementById("td2").innerHTML = '-';
        document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = '-';
        numri++;
        break;

    case 1:
        document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = 'x3';
        numri++;
        break;


}
```

Comment: Can't you just reset `numri` to 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `numri++;` in `case 10:` with `numri = 1;` Something like:

```
function numrat() {
    switch (numri) {
        case 10:
            // your logic
            numri = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = 'x3';
            numri++;
            break;
    }
}
```

Simplified code snippet to explain the solution:

```js
function numrat() {
  switch (numri) {
    case 5:
      console.log(5);
      numri = 1;
      break;
    case 4:
    case 3:
    case 2:
    case 1:
      console.log(numri);
      numri++;
      break;
  }
}

var numri = 1;
var itr = setInterval(numrat, 100);

// Guarding for infinite loop purposes
setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(itr)
}, 1500);
```

Comment: no in this case i have taken the case 10 and case 1 but there are also case 9 , 8 etc .. It goess from case 1 to case 10 and than stop i want it to start again. When it goes on case 10 i want to start again from case 1

Comment: What are you complaining about? His solution works perfectly fine. Just add in the other cases.

Comment: _"case 9, 8 etc."_ were not part of the question. But I believe this will still work. Values of `numri` will go this way: 1 -> 2 -> ... -> 9 -> 10 -> 1 ...

Comment: yes like this but i want it to restart and start again please

Comment: I don't understand. It does continue in an infinite loop.